# Twitter Bootstrap template page jumps jumping past start of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using this [Twitter Bootstrap](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/one-page-wonder.html#services) template to create a one-page responsive site. It works really well, except I find that the HTML pagejumps do not work quite correctly.

For the About, Services, Contact page jumps in the navigation I find that they all scroll past the start of the div they are supposed to be jumping to.

This happens on the latest version of Chrome and Firefox. I am using Bootstrap 3.

I can't seem to find any documentation of Bootstrap's pagejumps.

Why do they seem to jump past the `<div>`?

Comment: are you able to add some example code? Your problem will be related to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10670 maybe.

Comment: @BassJobsen I'm not overly familiar with Bootstrap - this is the first time i've used it. So I don't actually know what code is causing the problem, although I presume it is in `bootstrap.js` somewhere. Can you see the problem on the template example I provided?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the same as mentioned in the bug report above.

You set a padding-top of 50 px on your body element to compensate the fixed navbar. When scrolling to a `div` this padding has no effect so your content will be hide by the navbar.

You could add some additional javascript to set a padding-top on the div you scroll to:

```
$('.navbar-ex1-collapse a').click(function() 
{
    $('.featurette').css('padding-top','0');
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $(link).css('padding-top','50px');
});
```

adding extra space in your html also will be a solution.